# Modify a traversable lens using a nested state transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, haskell-lens

I have an `OuterState` object that contains multiple `_objects` that should be modified using `nestedAction` which also requires access to the `OuterState` object. Hence, `nestedAction` is a nested state transformer that is run for each `InnerStateObject` like in this example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main where

import Control.Lens ((+=), makeLenses)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy
       (StateT, evalStateT, execStateT, get)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)

data OuterState = OuterState
  { _objects :: [InnerStateObject]
  , _count :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

data InnerStateObject = InnerStateObject
  { _value :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''OuterState

makeLenses ''InnerStateObject

startNestedAction :: StateT OuterState IO ()
startNestedAction = do
  get >>= liftIO . putStrLn . ("before: " ++) . show
  objects . traverse <~% execStateT nestedAction
  get >>= liftIO . putStrLn . ("after: " ++) . show

nestedAction :: StateT InnerStateObject (StateT OuterState IO) ()
nestedAction = do
  value += 10
  lift $ count += 100

main :: IO ()
main =
  evalStateT
    startNestedAction
    OuterState {_count = 0, _objects = map InnerStateObject [0 .. 2]}
```

The definition of `<~%` is missing in this example. The precedence is `infixr 2 <~%`. It should pass each value of `objects . traverse` to `execStateT nestedAction` and assign the result to `objects . traverse`.

How can I implement `<~%`? What is the type of it?

---

**dependencies:** lts-9.3

- [lens-4.15.4](https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.3/package/lens-4.15.4)
- [mtl-2.2.1](https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.3/package/mtl-2.2.1)
- [transformers-0.5](https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.3/package/transformers-0.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use objects >>= traverse (execStateT nestedAction) >>= assign objects
```

---

`object . traverse` is too coarse grained to elegantly express the update of the `count` field (implicit via `nestedAction`) during the traversal of the `objects` field. This is basically why the lens library has no operator `(<~%) :: MonadState s m => ATraversal' s a -> (a -> m a) -> m ()`: it does not behave well if its second argument modifies parts of the state that are also being targeted by the traversal in its first argument.

Comment: Your solution doesn't compile. The expression `gets objects >>= traverse (execStateT nestedAction) >>= assign objects` results in `Couldn't match type ...` errors. As far as I understand you it seems that it is not possible to implement `<~%`. I have an open mind on alternative solutions.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `use objects` instead of `gets objects`.